# Can I combine WCF .config files?

Tags: wcf

Is it possible to combine the app.config files and web.config files.  I am self-hosting the service and hosting it in IIS and find myself having to edit two different files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you could "externalize" your relevant config sections into separate files, and reference those from both `app.config` as well as your `web.config`.

Any .NET configuration section can be stashed into an external config file, so you can write:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings configSource="bindings.config" />
  <behaviors configSource="behaviors.config" />
  <client configSource="client.config" /> 
  ....
</system.serviceModel>
```

Now, your external files will look exactly like the relevant config section inside your config:

**bindings.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" />
<bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
       <binding name="......."  ...... />
   </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Note: Visual Studio's editor will complain about the `configSource=` attribute - but the Intellisense is mixed up - the configSource attribute **is** present on each configuration section, and **it does work** just fine!

Note #2: you cannot externalize the entire `<system.serviceModel>` since that is a **configuration  section group** - and those do not have any means to be put into external files, unfortunately.

Comment: but can you get intelli-sense to work on the individual files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just add the `<appSettings>` section from your app.config into the web.config and merge if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In the past when I've wanted to read a `serviceModel` config section from a custom file location I've defined a custom subclass of `System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost`, and then passed the location of the custom config file to that subclass.

The technique is described here: [Reading WCF Configuration From a Customer Location](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2008/11/26/reading-wcf-configuration-from-a-custom-location.aspx)

With this technique you should be able to, contrary to the claim made by marc_s, place the entire service configuration in your WCF configuration file (app.config, I presume) in your IIS configuration file, and then pass the location of the IIS config file to the custom `ServiceHost` subclass as described above.